# How to build a truth table based on user input

Tags: c

I'm a beginner C programmer and I'm trying to make a program that asks the user for a boolean function, then prints the truth table.

The user would specify input as a boolean expression like this one:

```
!b && (a || d)
```

How could I ask the user to input the boolean expression, and then use it later in the code?

Comment: what do you mean? Please provide an example

Comment: This question is not very clear. I suggest you start by describing the input and the desired output, e.g. what text do you expect a user to type?

Comment: This seems *way* to broad. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a minute to read [How to ask.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Show some research effort by adding the work you started so far.

Comment: Do you think of asking the user for the code (head and body) of a function? In that case it seems you will have to compile or parse it at runtime. That would be a challenging goal, even for experienced programmers. So I believe you must mean something else, so please elaborate. A lot.

Comment: That would be only a logical expression, not a function. Easier, but still quite some parsing.

Comment: Maybe you could define a grammar, with actions and use tools to generate a parser.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments have mentioned, this is typically a multistep process. I've built my own [truth table generator](http://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs103/cs103.1176/tools/truth-table-tool/) that works along the lines of what you're proposing. The general process for doing this looks something like this:

- **Scanning**: The input you get from the user is a raw string, which is just a series of characters. You ultimately need to get from that string to some internal representation that says what the string "means." The first step in doing this, typically, is to break the input apart so that you see the input as a sequence of individual logical units. For example, you might break the input `a && !b || (c && d)` into the sequence `[a]`, `[&&]`, `[!]`, `[b]`, `[||]`, `[(]`, `[c]`, `[&&]`, `[d]`, `[)]`. This way, each individual unit (typically called a *token* or a *lexeme*) represents something meaningful and you're no longer dealing with a string processing problem.
- **Parsing**. The next step is to take your stream of tokens and figure out what the expression "means." This is called *parsing*. For the application you're describing, I'd recommend looking at Dijkstra's shunting-yard algorithm, which starts with a series of tokens representing a mathematical operation and reconstructs the operator precedence from it. The preferred output from this step is a tree structure representing the structure of your formula, typically called a *abstract syntax tree* (AST) or an *expression tree*.
- **Evaluation**. At this point, you now have your AST, which shows the hierarchical structure of the expression. Now, you need to generate the truth table. You can do this by walking the tree to extract a list of variables, then going through all possible combinations of which variables are true and which are false. For each of them, you can walk the tree to determine what the expression evaluates to in that case.

If you're curious what this looks like in practice, the [source code](http://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs103/cs103.1176/tools/truth-table-tool/js/) for the truth table tool I linked above is available here and is broken down into these steps. You can see the scanning, parsing, and AST logic to get a feel for what things look like.

Comment: Okay. I don't think my programming skills are enough for this kind of program yet. Thank you for your answer anyways!

Comment: @yacc As someone who teaches a lot of new programmers, I think that it’s not all that unreasonable to suspect something like this isn’t too challenging to do. I think this is one of those areas where it’s surprising how tricky it is and how many steps are involved.